# Contraction of past form of 失う？

Tags: kanji, conjugations

While looking at example sentences, I came across this on tangorin:

彼{かれ}は視力{しりょく}を失{うし}った。

My understanding is that this is still the verb 失{うしな}う. Searching for the kana form うしった hasn't led to any results.

If all this is true, why is part of the verb being truncated? Is this a common shortening?

Comment: This looks like an error in the database.

Comment: @Earthliŋ lol, I was afraid that might be the case. I've seen more than one; it makes me a little wary of taking tangorin examples.

Comment: It's making the same error on 整う and 襲う ... some sort of bug I suppose.

Comment: I think its is a bug. It should be 失った。